# Build a large list of possible combinations of a vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a list/vector/... from something like this:

```
elements <- c("a","b","c")
```

that gives me combinations of every entry of `elements` with all other entries of `elements`. These combinations should go from `length 1` to `length(elements)`. The result should therefore (if I haven't missed a combination) look like this:

```
combinationsvector <- c("a","b","c", "ab", "ac", "bc", "abc")
```

or:

```
combinationslist <- list("a","b","c", "ab", "ac", "bc", "abc")
```

I don't want to distinguish between `"ab"` and `"ba"`, those are the same thing for me. This should result in `{2^K}-1` combinations (I don't need the empty entry but it wouldn't hurt either). This is for a model averaging exercise and I'm trying to get all possible variable combinations of my dataset. In reality, `elements` is larger than 3.

Comment: its super close and I wouldn't have asked, had I found the other question. I'll leave it though because of what you point out (until we find the real duplicate which probably exists). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `combn` to generate those combinations. `combn` allows you to pass an anonymous function which can be used to `paste` the combinations together.

```
unlist(lapply(sequence(length(elements)), function(i)
    combn(elements, i, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ""))))
#[1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "ab"  "ac"  "bc"  "abc"
```